# How do I set up an email server using no ip?

Tags: email, arch-linux

I have a no ip account, and I want to use my home server (which is running arch linux) for email. I don't know what I'm supposed to put in the MX header field; am I supposed to put the hostname on my server, or my no ip url? I have very no experience with email servers.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Step one, verify that your ISP even permits you to run an SMTP server.  Most don't and any incoming or outgoing email will be blocked as a form of SPAM prevention.  Step two, start reading a book about your prefered MTA, running your own MTA is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The MX record in DNS should contain an A (or AAAA) record that resolves to your current IP-address.

I want to point out that most broadband providers in "civilized" countrys are blocking port 25 for their users because of problems with spam only allowing relaying via their own mail system (where users are often required to authenticate before relaying).